# Mouse movement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having intermittent problems with a javascript drag and drop operation on a web page.

It uses the evtobj properties and the 'document' properties to calculate the position of the mouse at any time.

Here are the lines that calculate the x and y mouse position :

```
        var xMousePos =evtobj.clientX + $(document).scrollLeft()

        var yMousePos =evtobj.clientY + $(document).scrollTop()
```

This js works intermittently and the problem seems to be due to the evtobj having miscalcuated the mouse position.

Repeated attempts of this drag and drop operation results in it working eventually - interestingly it never stops working once it starts.

Also if I click on the web page explicitly prior to starting the drag and drop operations it seems to work from the start.

Could it simply be a time lag issue? In other words the system is taking time to display the web page information and then be ready to handle the mouse movements.

Furthermore, if after some successful drag and drop actions I then scroll down the web page it starts to fail again for a period.

Is there a way I can delay operations until the system is completely ready - or can I do my own checks prior to allowing the drag and drop operation to begin?

-mike

Comment: You just shared 2 lines of code and lots of presumptions. Do you have a verifiable and testable case? Please show more code.

Comment: Either way you could do a small test like: `jQuery(function($) { myDragDrop();  
$(window).on("load", myDragDrop);
});` and see if it works once DOM is ready and window is loaded

Comment: Who is your `evtobj`?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: @Roko See jsfiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mapbpk/nzxha569/) I cannot get the drag n drop to work here as it relies on data being supplied by other web pages via json and I can't see how to do this in jsfiddle? But you can see the full js code here. The idea of putting in  a web page 'load' test prior to allowing drag and drop make sense - perhaps you can suggest how and where I could incorporate that test into the existing js code?

Comment: @Roko I have improved this by adding the line: `window.onload = function() {dragobject.initialize()};` which prevents the drag and drop starting until the window is fully loaded - this also has improved the same problem when I was haviong when I scroll up/down the web page. Thanks.